# Opara CSS button::after {padding:...} Bug

Tags: css, opera, padding

I need to add the layer under the  tag using before/after. But in Opera browser it is wrong calculates the padding property that is attached to a `button::after` pseudoelement (with other tags it is works good). It is begins to increase only if I will set a much bigger value.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/c8756/ (see in Opera and then in any other browser)

I have tried to set the various `display` values to both button and ::after elements, but anyway it does not works.

Is there any ways to fix the bug in Opera without touching of HTML?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need `::after`? `outline: 6px solid #d00;` seems to have the same visual effect: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/c8756/1/

Comment: Yes, because I have mach complex CSS to stylize ::after, there have to be border, box-shadow and border-radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://codepen.io/morewry/pen/rJmCg.  Remove `display`, `width`, and `height` and add `right` and `bottom`.

```
a::after,
button::after {
    content:"";
    padding:6px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-6px; top:-6px; right: -6px; bottom: -6px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Technique as http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/

Note that replaced elements (which includes most form elements), br, hr, and img aren't going to play nice with ::before and ::after.

Comment: I thought it is impossible to fix this issue using just CSS so I have already fix it using JS. So now I will remake it using your code. Thank you for help!